# Writing optional bean dependency injection by bean name

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-framework-beans

I've read some articles on optional bean dependencies, it is usually suggested to use java Optional class, or spring ObjectProvider class.

Those do work, but my case is a little different. What if in my context there are multiple beans of the same type, which annotated with `@Qualifier` and I don't know if there is a bean I need among them. And I need the one with the specific name.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package")
public class MyClass {

 private final MyOptionalBean myOptionalBean;

 MyClass(ObjectProvider<MyOptionalBean> myOptionalBeanObjectProvider) {
     this.myOptionalBean = myOptionalBeanObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(() -> null);
 }

}
```

The example above works. But now imagine, that there are multiple MyOptionalBean beans registered in my context, those beans are named. How do I write the similar code as above, but tell spring to look by the name of specific instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Autowired(required = false)` and `@Qualifier` in combination:

```
MyClass(@Autowired(required = false) @Qualifier("foo") MyOptionalBean myBean)
{
    // myBean will be null if no bean with the qualifier exists
}
```

Comment: Just tested your suggestion and it works for me, although Intellij Idea gives a warning Cannot find bean with qualifier 'foo', but that's okay, I guess